# Display post with specific role

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called `quiz` and custom category for quiz called `quiz-type`. I also have two roles: `candidate` and `recruiter`.

I had created two categories in quiz type which are also `candidate` and `recruiter`

Now I want to show if the current user's role is `candidate` but the quiz type is `recruiter`. It doesn't show my post and gives message that you are allowed for this quiz. Otherwise it works normally.

I am new to PHP so I didn't know how to make it work.

Comment: What's the code you use to show posts?

Comment: please put your code in question

Comment: ok, i have to find the code, since this custom post type was already present in my theme.